# Accessing variable outside function without using then function-Protractor

Tags: javascript, automation, jasmine, protractor

Is it possible to use a variable value outside the function without using then function ?

I am trying the below code:

```
describe('My Test', function() {
    var index_global=0;
    it('Test starts', function() {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get('https://www.w3schools.com/angular/');

        browser.sleep(5000).then(function(){ 
        });
        var results = element.all(by.css(".sidesection>p>a"));

        results.getText().then(function(text){
            var index=text.indexOf("HTML Includes");
            console.log("Index obtained is- "+index);
            index_global=index;
        })  
        console.log("Index i want outside the function - "+index_global);   
    })
})
```

The reason is because I have to use this index value mutiple times in my code in the same IT block and I cannot use `.then` function everywhere. Any input?

I am aware that if i use the below code it will give me the `index_global` value but I was wondering if there could be any alternative solution to this:

```
.then(function(){
        console.log("Index i want outside the function - "+index_global);
    });
```

Comment: No, you can't. It's asynchronous, that's why you have to use `.then`.

Comment: If you assign a different value to `index_global` inside a `.then`, that value will only appear after moving to the next `IT` block.

Comment: Yes you can, but it depends on your config / setup. Do you already use TypeScript / Node7? If so you can use the `async/await` method. You can do something like this `const text = await results.getText();`. It will wait the script execution until the promise is resolved and the text is fetched. You can then do everything with the `text` variable within your `it`-scope